# Can't get going with QML, Python and QT Creator on Mac OS

Tags: python, qt, qml

I'm having a bear of a time getting going with Python QML development on Mac OS. So first I got everything working under Windows, figured out how to set up and point to the appropriately set up Python environment, and eventually I was able to just press the run button in Qt Creator and there it is, the QML hello world template for Python pops up a Window. Fantastic.

So now I go to Mac OS and do the exact same thing. When I press the run button, I get the red exclamation point and the message

```
"No device configuration set".
```

I have no idea what that means.

So I tried running from a Terminal window. There I get the message.

```
main.qml:1 module "QtQuick" version 2.13 is not installed
```

So I go to the Maintenance tool for Qt Creator and make sure to install that version of QtQuick for MacOS. But it makes no difference - I still get the error.

What do these two error messages mean? Sorry for the newbie questions, I'm new to Qt Creator and QML.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to both problems, which as it turns out are separate problems. The cause of the first problem was that when QT Creator was installed, it set up the default build environment to be for ARM cross development. I don't even get how this works for Python, and it was a large pothole to fall into. Maybe the installer saw the ARM compiler that I use for embedded development on my machine. In any case, I was able to compare the configuration to the Windows version of QT Creator to sort it out.

The second problem is a QtQuick version problem. Apparently the version of QtQuick in Pyside2 is older than what was called out in the template code that Qt Creator generated. I set the version called out in the QML to 2.0 and it works. I still don't know what version of QtQuick is included with Pyside2, and don't know how to figure it out, other than to start increasing the version called out in the QML until it breaks.